# DApp on http://localhost:3000/, able to connect via metamask, but not with my personal wallet

Tags: solidity, dapps, goerli

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/wallet_connect/example to connect my custom wallet to my DApp which is on React. I am running DApp from 'npm start' on http://localhost:3000/ but I get the error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
```

on

```
_sessionStore = _wcClient.sessionStore;
```

from code: https://pub.dev/packages/wallet_connect/example

I also see below error:

```
Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 52550
```

RPC URL: http://localhost:3000/

When I use MetaMask, it works. It is on Goerli testnet